# how to find url from id and name in carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have model message, and attach file

```
class Message
    has_one :attach_file
end

class AttachFile
    mount_uploader :path, FileUploader
end

class FileUploader
    def store_dir
        "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end
end
```

I have controller list messages with attach file.

```
class Controller
     def index
         message = Message.join(:attach_file).select('messages.*, attach_files.*')
         render :json => message
     end
end
```

I try many way to retrieve attach file url, it works on public bucket because i set url from bucket name, id, name attach file. In case of private public, it require access key and signure, expires.
Is there any carrierwave's way to find attach file url

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? How to use raw SQL SELECT with carrierwave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. If you're using `select` in this way you have no access to CarrierWave's methods on the associated model. `select` in general has very few use cases; you probably shouldn't use it.
2. `render json` ignores associations unless you tell it to `include` them (or you've already overridden the model's `as_json`, or you're using a custom serializer, etc...).

A bonus semi-problem is that `join` isn't really what you want here. The idiomatic way to avoid N + 1 queries is `includes`.

```
def index
  messages = Message.includes(:attach_file)
  render json: messages, include: :attach_file 
end
```

Even better than `include: :attach_file` would be to use a tool like [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) to let the view layer handle your json serialization, but this answer's already long enough as it is.

Comment: I actually use active_model_serializers. The example above is just simple case. But you know, when you have complex query, we need to join many tables. In that case, we need way to get url from raw information like id, name... Is it possible?

Comment: If you want to use CarrierWave's `url` method, you need an instance of the model you called `mount_uploader` on. In your case it means not using `select` to collapse all the data into a single table. Otherwise you have to calculate it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
message = Message.find params[:id]
file_url = message.attach_file.path.url
```

Comment: i know that way, but i can't do that. Example above is just demo how the case is. Because, if you list all message with attach file so we can't do that way

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand why it wouldn't work.  Can you update the question with what goes wrong when you use the above code?

Comment: it is't wrong, you can do that, but it has problem when you must list all message with attach file. I assume you must take Message at the main class to query sql because you sometimes need to join with User.